# wpf windows project like Outlook Layout

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, window

I need to design an **wpf windows application** with **c#**. There will be a side menu. Which will be same for the entire application. When i click on the each menu item, corresponding page should display on the right side of the application, i don't want tabbed document

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I think you'll have to be more specific about your requirements... WPF will enable you to create a side menu in many different ways. You could even use a `TabControl` with `TabItems` and custom `Template`s to achieve what you suggested. Remember with WPF, a tabbed document doesn't have to look like a tabbed document and it seems that you want this same functionality, albeit on its side.

Answer (score 0):

What you want it application with navigation, take a look at [this MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx) for navigation and [like this](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/) for understand how to do that using MVVM.

The idea is you have your pages bound to navigation item selection. Read about datatemplates and datatype attribute of it.